# Asking for an specific bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I am asking for this specific type of bibliographystyle and not could get it yet.

Many thanks for any help.

> (in text) Jones et al. (2005)
>
> (citep) (Devlou & Zaparolli, 2013)
>
> (bib) Van Krevelen, D.W. (1990),“*Properties of Polymers. Their Correlation with Chemical Structure, Their Numerical Estimation and Prediction from Additive Group Contribuition*”, 3º ed., Elsevier, Amsterdam.

Comment: You have tagged this question with both `biblatex` and `natbib`. The two packages are fundamentally incompatible. Which one do you want to use? Do you need this bibliography style for the submission to a journal?

Comment: Natbib, I'd like to tagg with Bibtex, sorry. To second question: yes.

Comment: If you want to submit to a particular journal, do check if they provide a LaTeX template. Often these templates contain instructions for the bibliography, and if you are really lucky they may tell you which `.bst` file to use (they may even advise you to use one of the standard styles even though the output is not exactly the same as in the printed article: often LaTeX is just an intermediate step and not the final product and they may have other ways to produce the final bibliography) or provide a custom one for you.

Comment: Thank you for all, unfortunately they provide a LaTeX template with bibitems, not using Bibtex...

Comment: Ah, well. It would have been too easy. If you have only very few entries it might be an option to format them manually. Alternatively you could take a style that is quite close to what you want and then tweak the resulting `.bbl` file before you paste it into the document. Do note though that some `natbib` features are not available unless your manually-produced `\bibitem` bibliography has a special form. Double check if the journal actually supports `natbib`.

Comment: OK, many thanks!